# Python code to combine to columns in another column

Tags: python

I have the next python code to combine 2 columns in another one. Column 1 and 2 are combined to column 3. Suppose I have in column 1 the value “00” and column 2 the value “02”, I want to combine the two columns in column 3 to arrive as 0002, yes all without quotes the final result

But the script gives the results as for example ""00""02"" not 0002. Check photo.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('C:/asg/ftpfiles/output/NEWCATZ.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) >= 2:
            row[1] = row[1].replace('*', '00').zfill(4)
            row[2] = row[2].replace('*', '00').zfill(4)
            row.append(row[1] + row[2])
        rows.append(row)

with open('C:/asg/ftpfiles/output/NEWCATZ_updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
       writer.writerow([str(val) for val in row])
```

How can be fixed the code to make the results as 0002 or 0020 or 0102, etc., without quotes?

Note in the code Column B is the Column 1, Column C the Column 2 and Column D is the Column 3 who receives the results obviously. I’m using the numeric columns format instead R1C1 or other labeling.

[image: Photo reference of the CSV File]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032). Instead add the appropriate data as text in your question.

Comment: Since your data has the double quotes as part of the data (i.e., the first value in column B appears to be `'"00"'` and not `'00'`, it makes sense that you get what you're getting if you just add them together. Will all values in B and C consist of two digits in quotes, or can the number of digits vary? Do all values reliably have double quotes around them for the files you have to process? Instead of sharing a screenshot of Excel, you should share the first few lines of the actual .csv file, and share what you want the matching lines in the result to look like.

Comment: The data is simply. One row can be Column 1 “00”, Column 2 “01” and results are shown as in photo ""00""01"" in Column 3. There is no sense to put thousands of value that are similar.

Comment: `row.append(row[1].strip('"') + row[2].strip('"'))` perhaps?

Comment: Have a look at the linked article. What's up with the `.replace()` of a character that doesn't appear to be in your data? If it is, you should share (a sample of) the data, so we can tell. Giving people that are trying to help you improve your question lip isn't going to get you an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the row.append(row[1].strip('"') + row[2].strip('"')) it kills the format 00 and for example value of “01” is converted to 1 without zero and and when you combine is a false results for example “01” + “02” with that will be 12 and is wron it must be 0102

Comment: About the replace characters * in this case is ok to convert to 00, because if not when the quotes are removed it will cause error the *. The * I want to be 00 that is fine and works fine.